# SwiftUI - List order

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm noticing when adding items to a `List` they are out of order. The items are being added using `Core Data`, in my main `View` I show a `sheet` and then a user selects an item it's added to my main `List`. I assumed the items would be added in some kind of order from first to last.

My main view fetching CoreData items

```swift
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Items>

List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.city)
    }
}
```

Core Data saving items in the `sheet` view.

```swift
func addCity(_ city: String) {
    let fetchrequest: NSFetchRequest<Items> = Items.fetchRequest()
    fetchrequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "city = %@", city)
    do {
        let items = try viewContext.fetch(fetchrequest)
        if !items.isEmpty {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            print("item exists")
        } else {
            let items = Timezone(context: viewContext)
            items.city = city
            try? viewContext.save()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming is wrong. You need to handle sorting yourself.

Comment: Add explicit sort descriptors to have fetched results sorted.

Comment: I noticed I missed sortDescriptors but I'm unsure how to order it by when it's been added. I used `NSSortDescriptor` for the key but that just orders it alphabetically.

Comment: @cole you need to add a new field to your entity, like creation date, and sort by this field

Comment: Fixed and working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a date key to my Core Data `Entity` to keep a timestamp worked. And sorting using `@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)], animation: .default)` fixed the issue.